# Swing tutorial issue

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to learn Swing in Java.  Right now, I am on the first tutorial, which is a Celsius/Fahrenheit Temperature converter.  Right now, the first tutorial program that I have written is not running correctly, and I cannot seem to find the issue.

Here is the code:

```
package learn;

public class CelsiusConverterGUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form CelsiusConverterGUI
     */
    public CelsiusConverterGUI() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        tempTextField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        celsiusLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        convertButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
        fahrenheitLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("CelsiusConverter");

        tempTextField.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                tempTextFieldActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        celsiusLabel.setText("Celsius");

        convertButton.setText("Convert");
        convertButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                convertButtonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        fahrenheitLabel.setText("Fahrenheit");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(tempTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(celsiusLabel))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(convertButton)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(fahrenheitLabel)))
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        layout.linkSize(javax.swing.SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL, new java.awt.Component[]{convertButton, tempTextField});

        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(tempTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 20, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(celsiusLabel))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(convertButton)
                    .addComponent(fahrenheitLabel))
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        layout.linkSize(javax.swing.SwingConstants.VERTICAL, new java.awt.Component[]{convertButton, tempTextField});

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void tempTextFieldActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    }

    private void convertButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        //Parse degrees Celsius as a  double and convert to Farhenheit.
        int tempFahr = (int) ((Double.parseDouble(tempTextField.getText())) * 1.8 + 32);
        fahrenheitLabel.setText(tempFahr + " Fahrenheit");
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(CelsiusConverterGUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(CelsiusConverterGUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(CelsiusConverterGUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(CelsiusConverterGUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new CelsiusConverterGUI().setVisible(true);
            }
        });

    }

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JLabel celsiusLabel;
    private javax.swing.JButton convertButton;
    private javax.swing.JLabel fahrenheitLabel;
    private javax.swing.JTextField tempTextField;
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

And this is the output:

[image]

I don't understand what could have gone wrong; I did exactly what the tutorial told me to do!  For reference, here's the tutorial.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/learn/creatinggui.html

Thanks!

Comment: There's nothing there. Is that the problem? What are you trying to add?

Comment: And what does _"is not running correctly,"_ mean?

Comment: The app is supposed to look like this (scroll down and it the launch button):  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/learn/index.html

Instead it looks like this:

http://imgur.com/VemmvE5

Comment: It actually works pretty neat for me.  I can't imagine why you get the results in the picture, as I can perfectly see the textbox, labels and button.  How are you testing your application?

Comment: Hoe does one de-iconify their program?  This is my first time using any type of code for creating GUIs.

Comment: Jorge_B:  In the netbeans editor, I am selecting the "run" tab and "run project".

Comment: @user3178966 In Netbeans right click on CelsiusConverterGUI and click run file. Likely you have another main class defined in your project that NetBeans is running instead of this file.

Comment: @ns47731 I just did that, and still got the same result.

Comment: @user3178966 Other problem might be your running java 1.6 but compiling with 1.7. Check your java version by using `java -version` in command window

Comment: Found it - I followed @ns47731's suggestion, and then went to 'run' -> 'test project'.  and then 'run' -> 'run main project'.  It works perfectly now.  Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2):

I've ran your code and it runs fine.
What Java have you installed?
[image: CelciusGUI]

I don't know NetBeans but does it build automatically? Some IDE's don't, so you might have to build your application explicitly.

Comment: Netbeans IDE 7.4 .  I am going into the run tab and clicking 'run project'.  If it's running fine on yours, there must be something wrong with the way I have my editor set up.  Do you have any suggestions as to what it could be?